What is the "instruction index" referring to during this Solana transfer snippet?
See the Solana doc on manually building an SOL transfer instruction: https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions#manual-sol-transfer
It shows the following snippet:
// Define the amount to transfer
const transferAmount = 0.01; // 0.01 SOL
 
// Instruction index for the SystemProgram transfer instruction
const transferInstructionIndex = 2;
 
// Create a buffer for the data to be passed to the transfer instruction
const instructionData = Buffer.alloc(4 + 8); // uint32 + uint64
// Write the instruction index to the buffer
instructionData.writeUInt32LE(transferInstructionIndex, 0);
// Write the transfer amount to the buffer
instructionData.writeBigUInt64LE(BigInt(transferAmount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL), 4);
 
// Manually create a transfer instruction for transferring SOL from sender to receiver
const transferInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
  keys: [
    { pubkey: sender.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: receiver.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
  ],
  programId: SystemProgram.programId,
  data: instructionData,
});
 
// Add the transfer instruction to a new transaction
const transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction);

The line const transferInstructionIndex = 2 confuses me. What is this instruction index? What does it refer to? I don't see a definition for this anywhere in the documentation.

I found similar definition in @solana/web3.js source code.
Refer to @solana/web3.js/src/programs/system.ts "SYSTEM_INSTRUCTION_LAYOUTS".
  Transfer: {
    index: 2,
    layout: BufferLayout.struct<SystemInstructionInputData['Transfer']>([
      BufferLayout.u32('instruction'),
      u64('lamports'),
    ]),
  }

So I infer that Solana's Rust source code for transaction should also define the mapping of index.
Then I found its definition in solana rust source code.
Refer to https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/system_instruction/enum.SystemInstruction.html#variant.Transfer
The Transfer item in enum index is 2.
pub enum SystemInstruction {
    CreateAccount {
        lamports: u64,
        space: u64,
        owner: Pubkey,
    },
    Assign {
        owner: Pubkey,
    },
    Transfer {
        lamports: u64,
    },
    CreateAccountWithSeed {
        base: Pubkey,
        seed: String,
        lamports: u64,
        space: u64,
        owner: Pubkey,
    },
    AdvanceNonceAccount,
    WithdrawNonceAccount(u64),
    InitializeNonceAccount(Pubkey),
    AuthorizeNonceAccount(Pubkey),
    Allocate {
        space: u64,
    },
    AllocateWithSeed {
        base: Pubkey,
        seed: String,
        space: u64,
        owner: Pubkey,
    },
    AssignWithSeed {
        base: Pubkey,
        seed: String,
        owner: Pubkey,
    },
    TransferWithSeed {
        lamports: u64,
        from_seed: String,
        from_owner: Pubkey,
    },
    UpgradeNonceAccount,
}

